# Why jmeter/blazemeter is not recording web actions which are in angular?

Tags: angular, jmeter, liferay, recording

I have a portal which is mix of both liferay and angular. Although its recording all actions that are in liferay, its not recording actions which are in angular at all. Any possible causes?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter/BlazeMeter (if you're talking about the [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)) will record only those "actions" which trigger [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

If the "action" happens only on client/browser side it won't be recorded. So check i.e. "Network" tab of your your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and see if any HTTP request is being fired when you perform an "action". If it is the case - check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

Comment: all the actions are in https